# What does this conditional probability mean?

Tags: probability

I'm reading a cryptography textbook. It defines a finite set of messages $\mathcal{M}$. It then goes ahead and talks about the following probability:

$$Pr[M=m\wedge M'=m'\mid M\neq M'],$$

where $M$ and $M'$ are random variables on the set $\mathcal{M}$ with equal distributions. It's intuitively clear what is meant by this, but formally I don't really know how to compute with it. For example what is

$$Pr[M=m\wedge M'=m'\wedge M\neq M']?$$

I need to define a probability space somehow and express these events as sets, but it doesn't seem obvious how to interpret them.

ps. I haven't touched probability theory for a while...

Answer (score 2):

If $m\ne m'$, then
$$
[M=m\wedge M'=m'\wedge M\neq M']=[M=m\wedge M'=m'].
$$
Otherwise, that is, if $m=m'$ (but this case is never considered),
$$
[M=m\wedge M'=m'\wedge M\neq M']=\varnothing.
$$
If $M$ and $M'$ are i.i.d. with distribution $(p(m))_{m\in\mathcal M}$, then
$$
P[M=m\wedge M'=m']=p(m)p(m'),
$$
and
$$
P[M\ne M']=1-P[M=M']=1-\sum_{m''}P[M=m''\wedge M'=m''],
$$
that is,
$$
P[M\ne M']=1-\sum_{m''}p(m'')^2,
$$
hence, for every $m\ne m'$ in $\mathcal M$,
$$
P[M=m\wedge M'=m'\mid M\ne M']=\frac{p(m)p(m')}{1-\sum\limits_{m''}p(m'')^2}.
$$

Comment: @Dear dedicated downvoter: I have no doubt you take great pleasure following my posts and downvoting them systematically and, in a way, I feel proud of rendering you this service. Unfortunately, I am afraid that recently, you let yourself be carried away: to stay under MSE radars, one downvote a day was perfect, now your rhythm is at two downvotes a day, so I fear for you. Please, just stay (anonymous and) at one downvote per day, 'cause you see, if ever you get detected I would miss you. All the best.